# Query on MongoDB fields

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with `java 3.0 driver`. In the manual I only found `find()` and `findOne()` which will give me all the document. 
I have a scenario like I should get the `_id` value  by querying. for eg in SQL select `_id` from table name.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("557660c074cd60207e337aed"),
        "contactMethodId" : [
                {
                        "contactMethodId" : "contactMethodId",
                        "contactMethodUsageTypeCode" : null,
                        "contactMethodTypeCode" : "contactMethodTypeCode",
                        "contactMethodValue" : "contactMethodValue",
                        "contactContentTypeCode" : "contactContentTypeCode",
                        "contactContentMaxSize" : "contactContentMaxSize",
                        "comment" : "comment",
                        "preferredInt" : "preferredInd",
                        "effectiveStartDateOfContact" : "effectiveStartDateOfContact",
                        "effectiveEndDateOfContact" : "effectiveEndDateOfContact",
                        "standardizedIndOfContact" : "standardizedIndOfContact",
                        "lastVerifiedDateOfContact" : "lastVerifiedDateOfContact"
                }
        ]
}
```

`_id` is generated by default.

I want something like select `_id` from table name and I should get `ObjectId("557660c074cd60207e337aed")` in java. Any suggestions.

Comment: Use [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) on `_id` field. `db.coll.find({},{'_id': 1})`.

Comment: How will i do this in java?

Comment: Follow [this](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb) very helpful for beginner in java with mongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MongoIterable<Document> = mongoClient.getDatabase("foo")
   .getCollection("bob")
   .find()
   .projection(new Document("_id", 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following :

```
BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject();
projection.put("_id",1);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(new BasicDBObject(),projection);
```

And then read using loop on cursor.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Result : -"+cursor.next());
}
```

Comment: I guess this is older version, i am using java 3.0 driver all those methods are deprecated in this.

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli Not tested with 3.0 but should work

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli  Just tested. It is working with mongo java driver 3.0.1 also.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, tested with mongo version `3.0.3` and Mongo Java driver version `3.0.1`

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
public class demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017); // set host and port of mongo 
    DB db = mongo.getDB("demo"); // set DB name
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collectionName"); // set collection Name
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject project = new BasicDBObject();
    project.put("_id", 1); // set project to get _id 
    DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find(query, project); // find query with projection
    while(cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
      BasicDBObject object = (BasicDBObject) cursorDoc.next();
      String _id = object.get("_id").toString(); // If required convert the _id to String
      System.out.println(object); // print _id with object 
      System.out.println(_id); // print _id as a String
    }
  }
}
```